# In OpenLayers how can I enable a user to change a point into a line

Tags: openlayers, modify-interaction

Using ol3 I can use ol.interaction.Modify to enable users to move points, and add, move and delete vertices of lines and polygons.

Is it possible to enable users to change a point into a line (or a polygon)? One use case is where they have identified houses with points at a low zoom level, but now want to go to a higher zoom level so want to show the same houses as polygons.

I can think of one way (by providing a special button), but is there any more natural OpenLayers way?

Comment: First, you don't need to change it to point from polygon to keep its shape. Second, you can remove point and create polygon by checking map level.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think I understand what you are saying, but I don't think it really addresses my issue.
On your first, I would like the user to be able to change a point to a polygon, not the other way round.
On your second, this sounds like something I could program in, but not something the user can do.

Comment: what about to create polygon which has the same points something like [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0,0]] then it looks like a point then allow users to modify it to make polygon shape.

Comment: If there is no OpenLayers way then this is what I plan to do - add a button in my dialogue that the user can press to change the geometry type of a feature, eg a point into a polygon. Thanks.